# How can I clear the interpreter screen in Dr. Racket IDE?

Tags: ide, scheme, lisp, racket, the-little-schemer

Just starting into The Little Schemer, and have a very basic Dr. Racket IDE question:

1. How can I clear the interpreter screen?
2. How can I set the up arrow to display the previously-typed items (like in Bash) rather than the current behavior of scrolling up the screen?

My searches are coming up blank, possibly because I don't know the technical term for these actions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how:

1. Click on the "run" button, as you discovered
2. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>  + <kbd>p</kbd>

And this is the relevant page in the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/interactions-window.html).

Comment: Is it possible to clear DrRacket's interpreter using the racket code?

Answer (score 4):

## 1 clear interactions window

As you found out, pressing <kbd>RUN |></kbd> starts up a new instance of the selected language, runs everything in the definition window and clears everything you've done in interactions window (repl).

## 2 get previous entries like in a shell

a) In the Racket IDE you can hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with arrow keys to get to previously written statements in the interactions window.

b) Racket can be run from terminal too. When in CLI you type `racket` it starts up the read-eval-print loop with `racket` loaded and if you enter `(require xrepl)` as the first statement you have similar to `readline` capabilities with up-arrow to get previous, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to search history and REPL-commands like `,apropos`, `,help`  and so on. It's called [eXtended REPL](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html?q=xrepl)

Comment: CTRL+arrow does not work in Mac - it's already bound by the system.

Comment: @elazar On a mac you use cmd instead of ctrl.

Comment: ctrl+cmd+arrow does what you need on a mac, in addition to the esc+P

Comment: I hadn't tried running it from the terminal, but that is very helpful.  (I didn't want to start a new instance; I just wanted to clear the window and put the prompt at the top.  The standard readline key combination ^L does that.)