# How can I get the previous command in DrRacket?

Tags: racket

Like [Racket - how to get the “previous executed command” in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011939/racket-how-to-get-the-previous-executed-command-in-bash-script) but with DrRacket. How can I get the previously executed command in DrRacket (like up arrow function in bash)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I clear the interpreter screen in Dr. Racket IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792203/how-can-i-clear-the-interpreter-screen-in-dr-racket-ide)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, or you can [define your own bindings](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html#(part._defining-shortcuts)).

Also, <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> skips forward instead of backward.

---

To help you remember:
<kbd>p</kbd>revious, <kbd>n</kbd>ext

Comment: Also ctrl + up (or down).

Comment: But not on Mac.

Answer (score 15):

cmd + ctrl + up (or down) for Mac

Answer (score 2):

It's now the same on mac as the original answer.
esc + p / n